# setuptools sdist package directory folder name

Tags: python-3.x

When I create a source distribution (`sdist`) of my python project "my-project" (below) with `setuptools`, like the one below to create a `.tar.gz` project, setuptools creates an encapsulating directory with the version number on the name inside of the `.tar.gz`. Is there anyway to remove that?

My Project:

```
my-project
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── example_pkg
│   └── __init__.py
│   └── my_program.py
├── setup.py
└── tests
```

setup.py

```
with open("README.md", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="my-project", # Replace with your own username
    version="0.0.1",
    author="DogEatDog",
    author_email="author@example.com",
    description="A small example package",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.6',
)
```

Running `python3 setup.py sdist` should create:

```
dist/my-project-0.0.1.tar.gz
```

Extracting this tarball `tar -xvf dist/my-project-0.0.1.tar.gz` will extract to:

```
my-project-0.0.1
```

With all of the source inside `my-project-0.0.1/<my source>`.

Is there anyway to change `setuptools` to create a tarball that will extract into the current directory instead of the named directory? Such that running `tar -xvf my-project-0.0.1.tar.gz` would extract into the current directory?

**OR**

Is there a way in `setuptools` to specify the name of the encapsulating directory? Such that `tar -xvf my-project-0.0.1.tar.gz` would extract to `my-chosen-dir-name` instead of `my-project-0.0.1`?

**OR**

Is there a way in `setuptools` to remove the version number from encapsulating directory? Such that `tar -xvf my-project-0.0.1.tar.gz` would extract to `my-project` instead of `my-project-0.0.1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell. There is no way to specifically do this directly with `setuptools`. In my situation, I ended up writing a python script that unzipped (untarred) the package produced by `setuptools`, then moved everything to a root directory, then created a new tarball, and finally replaced the original tarball.

I know this sounds convoluted, but the particular build system that the project is required to work with needed this. This situation may be more specific to those projects combining OpenShift, `.s2i` and `setuptools` packages as a distribution.